# SanDisk SSD Dashboard doesn't recognize SanDisk SSD Plus 240GB

Tags: windows, ssd

SanDisk SSD Dashboard 2.7.0.0 doesn't recognize my SanDisk SSD Plus 240GB. It says

> SanDisk SSD not detected

I'm on Windows 7.
The SSD shows correctly in Libre Hardware Monitor and CrystalDiskInfo.

CrystalDiskInfo reports Firmware `U2010RL` and model `SanDisk SDSSDA240G`.

I want to check if I have the current firmware and update if it's outdated. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After updating to version 3.1.2.5, it works.